# Печать в IE8

Tags: jquery, javascript, internet-explorer

В общем есть задача печати длинной таблицы, при window.print() печатается всё ужасно, подскажите плиз, где как печатать, может литературу, может сайт, где это всё описывается. Ну или скажите пару фишек, основная проблема: первая страница пустая, div с таблицей внутри перекидывает на следующую, ячейки бог знает как разносит, border'ы тоже неизвестно как показывает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Придётся сделать простой CSS для принтеров и подключать его, используя [атрибут media](http://htmlbook.ru/html/link/media)